# Do monomials form a basis for the vector space of real analytic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, analytic-functions

Does the set ${1, x, x^2...}$ form a basis for the vector space of real analytic functions over the real numbers? It seems obvious that they span, but not obvious that they are independent.

Comment: doesn't the Taylor series prove that they are ?

Comment: No, if it is a basis, then any element can be represented by a **finite** linear combination of the basis elements.

Comment: How could it? Every real analytic function would then be a polynomial.

Comment: Actually, they are I think clearly linearly independent but do not span.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought infinite linear combinations were allowed-- I've only done finite dimensional vector spaces thus far. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: There are various concepts of "basis" for infinite-dimensional vector spaces; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29#Hamel_basis).

Comment: @copper.hat :  seriously ? how can you say that when you know that obviously there are different kind of "basis", and that the one which extends naturally to infinite dimensional vector spaces are not the basis you are talking about ? so read the question (are they independent, do they generate the whole space), and you'll see why you comment isn't adapted at all.

Comment: @user1952009: What is your question?

Comment: @user1952009 What is the most natural extension of a concept, if not literally the same concept?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo : I don't understand your comment. and it is obvious that the natural infinite dimensional extension of finite dimensional vector spaces are Hilbert/normed/Banach spaces.

Comment: Discussions about what extension is the most natural are not fruitful. The OP should clarify what is meant by "basis". On the one hand, "basis for the vector space" would usually imply a Hamel basis; on the other hand, the OP wrote "I thought infinite linear combinations were allowed" in a comment. The tension between these two indications can only be resolved by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: NO.

Long answer:
It depends on your use of the word 'basis'. Remember that when working with infinite dimensional vector spaces you can define 2 types of basis. Schauder's basis and Hamel's basis.

$\textbf{1)}$ Hamel Basis: For any infinite dimensional vector space $V$ a l.i. collection of vectors $ HB = \{ v_1,v_2, \cdots \} $ is named a Hamel basis for $V$ if for every vector $ v \in V $ there is a $\textbf{finite}$ number of elements of $HB$ such that
$$ v = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N c_i v_i $$
where of course $c_i$ belongs to the corresponding field.

$ \textbf{2)} $ Schauder Basis: For any infinite dimensional vector space $V$ a l.i. collection of vectors $ SB = \{ v_1,v_2, \cdots \} $ is named a Sachauder basis for $V$ if for every vector $ v \in V $ there is a subset $\{ u_1, u_2, \cdots \} \subseteq SB$ such that
$$ v = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i u_i $$

Is the difference clear? In the first one you can only accept $\textbf{finite}$ linear combinations while in the second one you can have a series. 
The thing with the Schauder basis it is that they are often very difficult to work with. Banach himself asked if any separable Banach space had a Schauder basis. Years after this question was solved by Enflo. (No). That is a very disappointing thing for the fans of Schauder's basis because existence is one of the first things you want to ensure.

Comment: Note that the space of real analytic functions does not have a Schauder basis, so your last sentence might be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the other answer where the difference between a vector space basis (Hamel basis) and a Schauder basis was introduced, let me mention that in [this article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm142/sm14226.pdf) P. Domaǹski and D. Vogt show that the space of real analytic functions **does not have a Schauder basis**.

Note that the Taylor series expansion might lead to a different series at each point but in order for the monomials to form a basis one would need that have the *same expansion at every point*.