# Is Taylor Series changing from an uncountable basis to a countable basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, change-of-basis

Say we've got an analytic function $f(x)$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. It has an uncountable number of components in this basis, since there is one value of $f(x)$ for each $x$ and $x$ varies continuously.

When we do a Fourier transform and hence change the variable to $w$, there is still an uncountable number of components, because $w$ too varies continuously.

But, in case of a Taylor series, the function can be represented by a countable number of components: $[f(0)\,\, f'(0)\,\, f''(0)\,\, f'''(0)\, \cdots]$. In this case, the number of components changes from uncountable infinite to countably infinite, when we change the basis.

Am I interpreting this right? The number of components never changes when we change the basis of a finite-dimensional vector space. Why does the number of components change here?

Comment: "It has an uncountable number of components in this basis." What basis is that?

Comment: @bof The x-basis

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function
There exists distinct smooth functions with the same Taylor series.

Comment: What do you mean by "basis"?

Comment: @nicomezi I changed it to analytic function

Comment: @boof Basis functions are a set of functions whose linear combination spans the other functions. The x-basis is the set of functions $b_r(x)$ with $b_r(r)=1$ and $b_r(x  \neq r)=0$. r belongs to $(-\infty, \infty)$Such functions are uncountable.

Comment: Typically, a linear combination is defined as a sum of scalar multiples of *finitely many* basis vectors. So "the x-basis" is not a basis, since there is no linear combination that yields the constant $1$ function. For more, see the comments and answers to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772214/856).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the domain ${\mathbb R}$ of a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ has uncountably many points. If you want to produce the function values   by a random number generator independently for each point then you would have to call this routine an uncountable number of times. But already a continuous function, let alone an analytic function, is completely determined by its values on a dense subset of ${\mathbb R}$, e.g., the countable set of rationals: Given a counting ${\mathbb Q}=\bigl\{ r_n\bigm| n\geq1\bigr\}$ it is sufficient to store the list $(y_n)_{n\geq1}$ of function values $y_n:=f(r_n)$. In the case of an (entire) analytic function you can store the list of Taylor coefficients $a_n:={1\over n!} f^{(n)}(0)$ $(n\geq0)$ and have enough information to produce the exact value of $f(z)$ even for all $z\in{\mathbb C}$. Note that there are some very special functions where even a few dozen "tokens" suffice to define them at all points $x\in{\mathbb R}$, e.g., $\exp(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{1\over k!} x^k$.